# addTextField to an alert using UIAlertController error

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to add a text field to an alert to simply ask a user for their name which I will then store as a variable and then use.

However when I add the text field I keep getting this error:

> [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewCollectionCell: 0x145f38340; frame = (0 0; 270 24); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c6a8b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000281d80>>

I tried making `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` but that did not work

```
@objc func showAlert() {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join", style: .default))
    alert.addTextField()
    
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

I feel like this should be so simple but I don't know why it doesn't work!!! If you have any other suggestions as to how to ask the user for a name it would be appreciated as well. Thanks

Comment: It's a bug in iOS. There's nothing you are doing wrong and there's nothing you can do to stop the message. You should report the bug to Apple.